# Got undefined method `file_colon_line' in Scenario Outline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

After I executed the Scenario Outline I got the following message and the scenarios failed.

Examples:

```
  | ID  | mail           |
  | Abc | test1@mail.com |
  undefined method `file_colon_line' for #<Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow:0xbe09a88> (NoMethodError)
  | ABC | test2@mail.com |
  undefined method `file_colon_line' for #<Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow:0xbe09a60> (NoMethodError)
```

Some solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a [custom screenshot filename](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#custom-screenshot-filename) configured in `features/support/capybara_screenshot.rb` with:

```
require 'capybara-screenshot'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'

Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = File.join(Integrator.root, 'tmp', 'failures')
Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:cucumber) do |scenario|
  # only works with Cucumber 1
  path = scenario.file_colon_line

  # also works with Cucumber 2
  path = scenario.location.to_s

  # ...
end
```

where the `scenario` used to be of class `Cucumber::Ast::Background` for Cucumber 1 which had the [file_colon_line](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/v1.3.19/lib/cucumber/ast/location.rb#L22-L24) defined.

But `scenario` now returns `Cucumber::Core::Test::Case` for Cucumber 2 which doesn't have this `file` or `file_colon_line` anymore. It however has `location`, `location.file`, `location.line`, `location.to_s`.